# Spring boot validation with Database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, bean-validation, spring-annotations, spring-validator

I have a requirement which need to do a custom validation with bean . The validated metadata can be received from Oracle DB. so based on the DB metadata I want to make bean properties as optional or required , apply patterns and do a cross field validation.
Can anyone suggest best practices for these requirements.
I want do do all this in spring boot
Better if you could share some sample code for reference

Thanks